# javascript: prefix in function call

Tags: javascript, html, function-call

I have seen many examples for calling a javascript function in two ways on an event on a control in HTMP/ASPX etc. such as in the example below:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateOldStudent(field, rules, i, options) {
        if (document.getElementById('Type_IDComboBox').value == 'Old') {
            if (field.val() == '') {
                alert('Fill in your lower course details.');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ASPX:
With javascript:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Type_IDComboBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="javascript:checkOldStudent(this);">
```

And without javascript:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Type_IDComboBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="checkOldStudent(this);">
```

The behavior/output is same with both. But I could not figure it out.
What difference does it make by prefixing `javascript:` or not prefixing it?

Comment: No difference at all; the `javascript:` prefix is unnecessary.

Comment: OK then just for curiosity, how this term/mode evolved, any specific browser dependency, W3C rule/standard or something else and which was the original construct with or without and how it changed?

Comment: The "javascript:" prefix is only necessary when embedding a js call in an href, e.g. <a href="javascript:void(0);"...>. It is necessary in that context because the default browser behavior is to interpret the 'href' attribute as a url: but in this case we want the browser to execute a piece of javascript instead, so the prefix is necessary. Think of it as an instruction. By contrast, the default browser behavior for onchange and other javascript event handler attributes is to execute the content as javascript, so the instruction is not necessary there.